# Я хочу узнать как изменить цвет ссылку

Tags: html, style, color, link

Я хочу изменить цвет  ссылки , но не получается у меня
Я хочу чтобы  показали как нужно делать чтобы изменилось цвет ссылки
И я хочу узнать как сделать чтобы если у тебя есть 2 ссылки и хочешь чтобы их цветы изменились но не были одинаковыми цветом были разные цвета

Comment: `<a href="#" style="color: #ff0000;">click me</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю правильно ли я понял вас, но вот что-то написал по этому поводу

```css
a:hover {
 color: blue !important;
}
a:focus {
 color: green !important;
}
a.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
a.red:hover {
  color: black;
}
a.yellow {
  color: #cc0;
}
a.yellow:hover {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<p> Писать стили в HTML разметке нельзя, так как потом в стилях переопределить удастся только через !important, что в корне не правильно.<br />Обычно стили используют в HTML разметке только при дальнейшем использовании их в JS, так как скрипты как раз таки умеют переопределять стили вписанные в DOM.</p>
<a href="#" style="color: #ff0000;">Наведи или кликни на меня</a>
<br />
<a href="#" style="color: #cc0;">Наведи или кликни на меня</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<p>Так делать правильно - тут вписаны уникальные класссы для ссылок на которые можно ссылаться при написании стилей</p>
<a class="red" href="#">Наведи на меня</a>
<br />
<a class="yellow" href="#">Наведи на меня</a>
<br />
```

Comment: Спасибо большое